# How to login to ftp in one step?

Tags: windows, batch, ftp

```
C:\adc_ftp>ftp sysadmin:ftp@localhost <----Looking for a 1 line login like this
Unknown host sysadmin:ftp@localhost. <---doesn't work
ftp> bye
```

This works but not how I would like to log in:

```
C:\adc_ftp>ftp localhost 
Connected to myPC.xxx.com.
220-FTP server
    WarFTPd 1.82.00-RC11 (Sep 22 2006) Ready
    (C)opyright 1996 - 2006 by Jarle (jgaa) Aase - all rights reserved.
220 Please enter your user name.
User (myPC.xxx.com:(none)): sysadmin
331 User name okay, need password.
Password:
230 User sysadmin logged in from host localhost (127.0.0.1)
ftp>
```

I'm trying to make a batch file that logs into the ftp server. I tried examples like
[this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269), but it doesn't take the login information and just sits at the "Please enter your user name".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [example that you mentioned](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269), be sure to use the **-n** flag to disable auto-login

```
C:\adc_ftp>ftp -n -s:ftp_script.txt localhost
```

Where **ftp_script.txt** contains something like:

```
user
ftp
ftppassword
Some ftp commands...
quit
```

Answer (score 4):

To do this, you need to make a text file.

For instance, to get a file that is located at `ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/README` this is my text file:

```
open ftp.kernel.org
anonymous
root@kernel.org
get /pub/README
bye
```

I then call ftp using the `-s` parameter, like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eleven81\Desktop>ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

Which worked perfectly for me.

Comment: The separate txt file is what I was missing. I thought I could script opening ftp from the .bat. Thanks! (Now my bat file calls the .txt script.)

Answer (score 0):

## Auto-login to Filezilla in one step:

1. Create Site Profile in Filezilla, specifying the username and password (if you don't have one already)
2. Create a shortcut to Filezilla somewhere. (Mine's on the quick launch bar)
3. Right-click the shortcut to go into it's properties.
4. Append the end of the **Target** with `--site="0yoursiteprofile"`.
   The `0` is indicates it's a saved profile (as opposed to the default profile.)

The whole **Target** field should be something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe" --site="0yoursiteprofile"
```

Spaces, slashes and other symbols may need to be escaped if you have them in your profile name, so just avoid them, or read more about **[Filezilla's command-line switches](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))**.

That's all -- just click the shortcut to launch and login!

[image: img]

---

**Note** that within Filezilla's Shortcut's properties, you can also add a [shortcut key-combination](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/create-keyboard-shortcuts-windows-10) if desired.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
================  ftp.txt  =================
open "ftp.ZZZZZ.com"
user "username" "password"
cd public_html
prompt
hash
put thursday.htm
cd thursday_files
lcd thursday_files
mput *
bye
=============================================
ftp -n -s:ftp.txt
```